# Google Cloud PubSub with PHP - how to install classes on the App Engine server side?

Tags: google-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine-php

I'm trying to use the Google messaging system but I'm failing before starting.
I'm trying to start with a super simple app that only transmit a "hello world" message and then capture it. Saving it in DB and other tasks will be done after this service is up and running.

However I can't get it to work.I get the error:

> [my-app].appspot.com is currently unable to handle this request.
>   HTTP ERROR 500

On logs, I see the problem:

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Google\Cloud\PubSub\PubSubClient' not found in /base/data/home/apps/g~[my-app]/20170809t182312.403268501910529191/printHello.php on line 14

Line 14 is: `$pubsub = new PubSubClient([` which is copy paste from google documentation

Consider:

- The app is working fine without the: `use Google\Cloud\PubSub\PubSubClient;`. I delete everything except an `echo "... some text praying to make it work..."` and it is displayed. So no problem in app.yaml file or somewhere else.
- I was able to send a message from the topic detail page and receive it in web-console so all authorizations and enabling are done correct.
- on local machine, Intellij IDEA recognized the PubSubClient class after I installed beta components. The app is not working on local machine, but I did not even try it. I want to be able to make it work on the server first time.
- I checked and all files from local are present on the server as well.

What am I missing? I read all pages I found on cloud.google. ... and all I found on the internet but it seems nobody had a similar problem. So it must be something very simple that I'm doing wrong or have not done. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Cloud PubSub is not [by default](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/runtime#PHP_Enabled_extensions) enabled in GAE. You need to add it to your app code. From [Pure PHP](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/runtime#PHP_Pure_PHP):

> You can include other pure PHP libraries with your application by
>   putting the code in your application's directory, which is the same
>   directory that contains your `app.yaml` file.
>
> For example, you can create a symbolic link in your application's
>   directory that points to a library's directory. That link is then
>   followed and that library gets included in your application when you
>   deploy to App Engine.
>
> You can also include PHP libraries by specifying `php.ini` directives
>   and including PHP `include` statements in your code. However, the
>   preferred alternative is to use a PHP dependency management tool such
>   as [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/).

I'd check in Intellij IDEA where is the library/class located on your local system and symlink it into your app dir. It *might* be necessary to adjust the `use` statement and/or the symlink source dir to get things going.

Note: I'm a Python, not a PHP user, so take this with a grain of salt.

Comment: ( Multumesc frumos! )
Thank you. I've already did this with other classes that I've used for creating task queue. For Pub I could not get it to work. After much digging I found that there were other classes that I was missing completely.
I copy/pasted their bookshelf example but that one also complained that I don't have PHP 5.6 but only PHP 5.5. That is in gcloud, of course. I have Xamp with all versions up to 7.1.7. but could not use it.

So far I'll take a break from GC and play more with AWS. Will get back when more functionality goes out of beta.